# Multi-project-build - global plugin is recompiled midway through build and failed on "Symbol 'type sbt.io.IOSyntax' is missing from the classpath"

Tags: sbt

sbt version: from 1.4.0 still happening at 1.4.2

Previously working on 1.3.13

Multi-project build, a bare minimum version sample project is avaialble at https://github.com/raphaelNguyen/sample/new/master.

When starting sbt in sbt-sample, sbt failed to load with the error

Short description of the build:

Our project has a global plugin that holds all organisation settings and a separate plugin project which holds settings specific to some of our projects. The specific setting project depends on the global plugin project to add the global autoplugin to the requirements of the specific autoplugin.

The projects that need to use the specific plugin will then pull the specific plugin project in to their build project (in project/plugin.sbt) as project dependency as can be seen in structure below.

```
-+-- global-plugin - used as sample project when running sbt
 |
 +-- specific-plugin - dependsOn global-plugin
 |
 +-- sbt-sample - dependsOn sbt-sample-child and sbt-sample-other-child
 |     +-- sbt-sample-build - dependsOn specific-plugin
 |
 +-- sbt-sample-child
 |     +-- sbt-sample-child-build - dependsOn specific-plugin
 |
 +-- sbt-sample-other-child (not included in linked project above as unecessary to reproduce this error)
       +-- sbt-sample-other-child-build
```

With the above setup, when running sbt withthe following command in the sbt-sample directory:

```
SBT_OPTS="${SBT_OPTS} -Dsbt.global.plugins=Path\to\repo\sample\plugin-sample" sbt
```

results in the following output

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.2 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 11.0.8)
[info] loading global plugins from O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\project
[info] loading settings for project global-plugins from build.sbt ...
[info] loading global plugins from O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin
[info] compiling 3 Scala sources to O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\target\scala-2.12\sbt-1.0\classes ...
[info] loading settings for project sample-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from O:\Prj\github\sample\specific-plugin\project
[info] loading settings for project play-plugins from build.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\project
[info] loading settings for project global-plugin from build.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from O:\Prj\github\sample\sbt-sample\project
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] compiling 3 Scala sources to O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\target\scala-2.12\sbt-1.0\classes ...
[info] loading settings for project sbt-sample from build.sbt ...
[info] loading settings for project sbt-sample-child-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from O:\Prj\github\sample\specific-plugin\project
[info] loading settings for project play-plugins from build.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\project
[info] loading settings for project global-plugin from build.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from O:\Prj\github\sample\sbt-sample-child\project
[info] compiling 3 Scala sources to O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\target\scala-2.12\sbt-1.0\classes ...
[error] O:\Prj\github\sample\global-plugin\src\main\scala\iad\sbt\Projects.scala:4:8: Symbol 'type sbt.io.IOSyntax' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'trait sbt.IOSyntax1'.
[error] Make sure that type IOSyntax is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'IOSyntax1.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of sbt.io.
[error] import sbt._
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (ProjectRef(uri("file:///O:/Prj/github/sample/global-plugin/"), "global-plugin") / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

Does anyone know what might cause the global plugin to recompile and fail during recompiling even though it compled fine the first time around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sbt 1.4.3 (the latest) may have fixed your issue.

Comment: That certainly did it. Thanks.